# Cannot read property 'determineRelationshipType' when trying to save() Model with hasMany Relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm running into a tough bug when trying to save a record with the LocalStorage Adapter that has a hasMany relationship (Using Ember CLI). What I'm trying to do is save a product to a bag when a user clicks on a "Add to Bag" button. I'm getting this error in my console:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'determineRelationshipType' of undefined`

Product Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  bag: DS.belongsTo('bag')

});
```

Bag Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  products: DS.hasMany('product', {async: true})
});
```

Here's the action in the controller:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    addToBag: function(model) {
      var bag = this.store.createRecord('bag');
      bag.get('products').then(function(products) {
        products.pushObject(model);
        bag.save();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Would anyone have an idea as to what's going wrong? Or another way to approach this? Seems like a similar issue [was reported here](https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/123). Would greatly appreciate any help! Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, but haven't found a solution yet. This issue with Emberfire may be related: https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-investigated this issue and looks like it was addressed in a recent update to `ember-localstorage-adapter`. Specifically, the [reference to DS.RelationshipChange was removed](https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter/pull/89).

In my `bower.json`, I defined my `ember-data` version back to `1.0.0-beta.11` and also defined my `ember-localstorage-adapter` version to the latest version, `0.5.0`. Here's the relevant info in the `bower.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "****",
  "dependencies": {    
    "ember": "1.8.1",
    "ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.11",
    "ember-localstorage-adapter": "~0.5.0",
  }
}
```

This error is no longer appearing!

Answer (score 2):

I started a project using the emberfire adapter and ran into the same issue.

Without going to deep into this, it looks like ember-data beta.10 deprecated a feature that was necessary for hasMany to work. (Further reading https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/issues/123)

Downgrading to ember-data beta.8 fixed the issue for me.

This is necessary until the adapters (emberfire and/or localstorage) can be updated.

In my ember-cli project I did:

`rm -rf vendor/ember-data/
bower cache clean ember-data`

Edit files `vendor/emberfire/bower.json` and `vendor/emberfire/.bower.json` to say `"ember-data": "1.0.0-beta.8"`.

`bower install`

Comment: I downgraded to Ember Beta.8 and the issue was resolved. Thanks for the answer. I hope that when this issue is resolved in future versions of Ember data.

Comment: has there been any update on this? I tried upgrading to ember data beta.10 again, and the same issue occurred. For now, I'm back to 8 but would love to be able to upgrade at some point

Comment: No updates on my end. You may want submit a bug report to either or both the LocalStorage Adapter and Ember Data maintainers.