# createRecord, then set belongsTo results in Transaction Error

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After upgrading my application to Ember `1.8.1` and Ember Data `1.0.0-beta.11`, I am getting a very strange error when trying to set a `belongsTo` relationship between 2 models:

`Attempted to handle event didCommit on <***@model:order::**:**> while in state root.loaded.updated.uncommitted.`

This comes when I create an `order`, and try to assign the current `bag` to that order. Here's the relevant code in the `order` controller:

```
assignBag: function() {
  var newOrder = this.get('model');
  var shoppingBag = this.get('bag').objectAt('0');
  newOrder.set('bag', shoppingBag);
  this.get("controllers.order").send('saveOrder', newOrder);
  this.send('fireViewedCheckoutSegmentEvent');
}.on('init'),
```

The problematic line is `newOrder.set('bag', shoppingBag);`. By the nature of the error you would think that this would be because a newly created `order` had not been persisted in the database. But from the code in the route, it's clear that the order is saved before setting the `model` in the controller:

Here is the `order` route:

```
var OrderRoute = Ember.Route.extend(ResetScrollMixin, {
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('order');
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    if (model.get('length') < 1) {
      model = this.store.createRecord('order');
    }
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var order = model.objectAt('0');
    order.save().then(function(savedOrder) {
      controller.set('model', savedOrder);
    });
  }
});
```

If it helps, here's the code for the two models:

Order:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  bag: DS.belongsTo('bag', {async: true}),
});
```

Bag:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  order: DS.belongsTo('order'),
});
```

I have been banging my head against the wall for days on this. Does anyone have an idea of what's going on? Am I incorrectly setting up the `belongsTo` relationship? Both the order and bag models use the LocalStorage adapter.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So before the upgrade it worked? What version you upgraded from? I would assume that the changelog for the new version has a few clues.

Comment: One thing I had issues with in the upgrade to 1.8.1 was inconsistency in functionality of relationships that don't specify the async property.  I would look at the fact that one of the belongsTo has async:true and the other does not, and see if it works with both relationships using async or neither using it.

Comment: @givanse I upgraded from ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8, so quite the significant jump. I was having other [issues with the LocalStorage Adapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309726/cannot-read-property-determinerelationshiptype-when-trying-to-save-model-wit/26317739?noredirect=1#comment42532228_26317739) that prevented me from updating.

Comment: @LAW tried the relationships with both async: true and both not using async, did not work.